# jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery

So I am dealing with Jquery auto complete.

I include jquery and auto complete jquery stuff.

```
    <script src="../../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../jquery/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var townList = ["London","Manchester"]; //establish user town list
    $("input#townSearcher").autocomplete({source:townList});
}
    </script>

<input type="text" id="townSearcher" />
```

The AutoComplete does not work when i put Lon in or Manc for example, what am I missing in this simple example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to give it an object

```
$("input#townSearcher").autocomplete({source:townList});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/QsvpJ/)

here is the [autocomplete documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

**edit**

you may want to try using cdn

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have just attempted this, i find it odd how it works on your example and (nw i have edited my code) still does not work in my page.. there are 0 errors, 0 warnings and i do not think anything else is breaking it on the page. :/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the DOM is loaded.  You need to wrap your jquery in the onload event.

```
$(function() { 
  $("input#townSearcher").autocomplete(townList); 
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/keroger2k/AftpL/7/)

Comment: @mcgrailm I'm not for sure what you are seeing, but it works fine.  I don't have any CSS, but the autocomplete works just fine.  Type an 'L' or an 'M' and it will show the results.

Comment: I get error in ff4 say 'Error: $("input#townSearcher").autocomplete is not a function
Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/keroger2k/AftpL/1/show/
Line: 25"

Comment: @mcgrailm you were right.  the autocomplete src file i was linking to was getting a 403 forbidden.  Mine worked fine in chrome though.  Thanks for the update.